# Open CPN AIS Integration into QGIS

Tags: qgis, ais

Can AIS marine traffic live vessel data be integrated into QGIS?

I understand this could be possible using an OpenCPN plugin and Grass.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for this late answer but want to share this if you still need it. I used Vesselfinder, fairly the same to MarineTraffic, and I think I accomplished what you are trying to achieve.

I used a python script (with psycopg2 extension) that received the information via an API from Vesselfinder. The script saved the data in a PostgreSQL database (with PostGIS extension) and in QGIS a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database is accessible via the database manager. Every time the script runs (i used a Loop Bat. file, to let it run every 5 min) the data is updated en immediately visible in QGIS.

this is the python code to get data and store it in a db.

```
    # Import libraries
    import requests
    import pprint
    import json
    import sys
    import psycopg2
    import datetime

    # Make database connection
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=YOURDBNAME user=YOURUSERNAME password=YOURPASSWORD")

    # Get cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # Define headers
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    # Build URL
    url = 'YOUR VESSELFINDER/MARINETRAFFIC API URL

    # Execute HTTP request
    print('Get vessel positions from ' + str(url))
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    # Get result and store in database (point in 4326, convert date 2019-02-01 06:29:43 UTC)
    # Update scheepstrack
    if response.status_code == 200 :
        print ('Request OK')
        if len(response.json()) > 0 :
            i = 0
            while i < len(response.json()):
                YOURCOLLUMNAME = str(response.json()[i]['AIS']['NAME'])
                 YOURCOLLUMNAME = int(response.json()[i]['AIS']['MMSI'])
                 YOURCOLLUMNAME = float(response.json()[i]['AIS']['LATITUDE'])
                 YOURCOLLUMNAME = float(response.json()[i]['AIS']['LONGITUDE'])
                 YOURCOLLUMNAME = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(response.json()[i]['AIS']['TIMESTAMP'][:-4]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Insert new position
            insert_stmt = 'insert into YOURDBNAME ( YOURCOLLUMNAME, YOURCOLLUMNAME, "YOURCOLLUMNAME", "YOURCOLLUMNAME" ) values ( %s, %s, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s),4326), %s )' 
            cur.execute ( insert_stmt, ( YOURCOLLUMNAME, YOURCOLLUMNAME, YOURCOLLUMNAME, YOURCOLLUMNAME, YOURCOLLUMNAME ) )
```

This will create a real-time feed of you vessel(s)
Hope this is still to some use to you or somebody else that reads this.